# Help identifying a walkout door threshold and repair options

Tags: repair, doors, basement

The walkout door in my basement has a cracked threshold. I searched again and again on multiple online sites, Home Depot, and Lowes trying to find a make & model similar to mine, but couldn't find one. Does anyone recognize what this is and what are my repair options?

[image: walkout door threshold 1]
[image: walkout door threshold 2]

Comment: Looks like one that came attached to the door frame. You will probably need to just buy one of similar dimensions and cut it in.

Comment: @GregNickoloff Thanks! That's likely what I will end up doing. I plan to use [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/100202626) and cut one side square. Does this sound like an acceptable solution? Are there special considerations for below-grade thresholds that directly border a staircase? If there is anything to change, I might as well use this opportunity to do it right.

Comment: I guess so.. This one (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-5-5-8-in-x-3-ft-Silver-Brown-Fixed-Sill-Threshold-TS36A/100207958) looks to be a closer match and, being aluminum, maybe not so susceptible to water damage....

Comment: I saw that one too, but thought the aluminum ramp should face the outside (the door swings inside) and would be blocked by the staircase. Thanks for all your suggestions though! I've ordered the wooden one so will see how well I can make it fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick update so the question can be closed. I ended up cutting out the old one and installing a new [adjustable aluminum threshold from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-3-1-2-in-Wide-x-36-in-Silver-Adjustable-Height-Threshold-DAT39H/100121731). I had to saw open the hard black plastic and the aluminum ramp, breaking them into pieces. I also used an oscillating multi-tool to cut into the door jambs and scraped the old caulk around the perimeter. Finally I pried everything out. Installing was relatively easy. I just had to cut a few wood blocks to fill under the door jambs. With some cleaning, a fresh paint and caulk, the end result looks half-way decent:

[image: new threshold]

Answer (score 0):

It’s difficult to see the shape (profile), much less the dimensions from the photo.

Here’s Pemko’s 200 page catalog:

https://absupply.net/pdf/PemkoFullCatalog2012.pdf

Hopefully you can spend some time and find a match...or acceptable substitution. When you do, your local lumberyard can order it.

Comment: Thanks for the catalog. I find a few more catalogs and went through them all! However, this below-grade, walk-out basement door threshold appears somewhat of a rarity. I couldn't any that matches its un-symmetrical setup that directly borders a stair.